# nano 2.9.3 hides repeated characters

Tags: 18.04, nano

After my web provider upgraded to Ubuntu 18.04, I noticed that the nano editor (2.9.3) behaves strange when showing repeated characters in a word.

For example, this text ...

```
-----abc5
------abc6
-------abc7
--------abc8
```

... shows in nano as ...

```
-----abc5
------abc6
-abc7
-abc8
```

The magic starts only after 7 chars are identical.
When moving w/ cursor above, the hidden chars reveal gradually.

Other Ubuntu 18.04 installations don’t do that.

Google didn’t help.

Any ideas?

**----- UPDATE (04.06.2019) -----**

As requested ...

```
geohei@myserver:~$ hexdump -C testfile
00000000  2d 61 62 63 0a 2d 2d 61  62 63 32 0a 2d 2d 2d 61  |-abc.--abc2.---a|
00000010  62 63 33 0a 2d 2d 2d 2d  61 62 63 34 0a 2d 2d 2d  |bc3.----abc4.---|
00000020  2d 2d 61 62 63 35 0a 2d  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 61 62 63  |--abc5.------abc|
00000030  36 0a 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d  2d 61 62 63 37 0a 2d 2d  |6.-------abc7.--|
00000040  2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 61 62  63 38 0a                 |------abc8.|
0000004b
```

Comment: Could you post a hexdump of the file? You could use `xxd`.

Comment: Done! I updated the question. See above ...

Comment: Well the hexdump looks fine.

Comment: What terminal are you using? How are you connecting to your provider? SSH?

Comment: I use PuTTY as client from am Windows 7 machine to login via ssh. I noticed that when I login to another Unix machine (as intermediate), and then to my provider, the output is sometimes ok, sometimes not! Using `Ubuntu 14.04.6` as intermediate machine, the output is fine. However when I use `Debian GNU/Linux 8`, chars get hidden again (like for the use without intermedta).